# phpStrom adding files that were manually deleted to be commited

Tags: svn, phpstorm

In a SVN branch i did a big refractor step via script manually outside phpStorm.

After this in phpStorm i was able to manually add new files and modified files to be committed.But how can i add the deleted and moved files to be added to be committed.

Better is there any option to add all outside changes in a single step rather than manually checking the directory tree.

Thanks in advance

Comment: PhpStorm *should* pick up the changes automatically if you've enabled the integrated version control for the project. If not, simply, from the project view, right-click on the top-level folder and select Local History > Show. You'll get a tree of the changes with diffs and whatnot if necessary. Totally awesome feature.

Comment: Oh, and use git. SVN sucks.